# Checking a solution for a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose you have a differential equation, and after getting a general solution, you try to test whether other solutions (which you presumed non-equal to $0$ in the process of solving the equation) might be viable. You then equate them to $0$, plug them in you initial differential equation and get something like $-dy$ or $ dx$ and you need to ascertain whether $-dy = 0$ , or  $dx = 0$ holds true, or not....How do you do this?

Comment: Can you show an example? I think there is some misconception going on here.

Comment: $dx=0$ means $x=K$

Comment: @Ian https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706003/solving-the-differential-equation-2xydy-3x3y-1dx-0 where $-2(x+y)≠0$ but you later need to ascertain as for what happens when it does

Answer (score 2):

In general your question seems to be about separable equations $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x) g(y)$. When you assume $g(y) \neq 0$ and $f(x) \neq 0$, then you do this:

$$\int \frac{dy}{g(y)} = \int \frac{dx}{f(x)}.$$

This results in an equation of the form $G(y)=F(x)+C.$ I call solutions of this form "separable solutions" because you obtain them by separating variables. Zeros of $f$ typically just wind up coming in as domain constraints of these, so there isn't really a problem. But non-separable solutions arise when $g$ has a zero.

Usually the equation is nice enough that the solution to an IVP is unique. Since a solution to an IVP with $g(y_0)=0$ is of course $y \equiv y_0$, this means that if $g(y_0) \neq 0$ and the solution is unique then $g(y)$ will be nonzero forever.

So *in the case where the solution is unique*, you can solve for separable solutions by separating variables, and solve for constant solutions by searching for zeros of $g$. All solutions will be of one type or the other.

When the solution is not unique, you can find some solutions in this manner, but there may also be non-constant solutions with $g(y(x))=0$ for some values of $x$.